# cp command within php resulted in a partial copy

Tags: php, copy, partial, interrupt, cp

I have a small PHP script I wrote to help me push changes from staging to production.  I run both staging and prod on the same server so my script copies changes from staging folders to prod folder.

This has been working fine until today when I had a few instances when files were only partially copied over resulting in some down time.  I'm wondering if a user accessing a Web page using a file being copied at the exact same time resulted in an interruption of the cp command and a partial file copy.  Any ideas or solutions?

The copy command is basically:

```
exec( 'cp -Rfpuv /staging/folder/path /prod/folder/path' );
```

The server is a basic LAMP stack, with Apache 2, PHP 5, MySQL 5 and CentOS 5.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/examples.html) as well.